# Syncing a raycast over the network (Mirror/Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, mirror

I have a very simple building script for a first person survival game for testing, the host and client can press 'T' and it will spawn a cube onto the terrain which moves around with the raycast hit (coming out from the players camera)

For the host, it works fine, the client is able to see it move around with the network transform attached to the cube.

However for the client, currently it will spawn but it seems to spawn in the middle of the map as if it is not detecting the clients raycast? (this is from the hosts perspective, it is fine what the client see's) or either it is fighting with the host's raycast (not quite sure) It also looks like it is fighting for the clients raycasted position potentially, the cube is flashing on and and off occasionally very very quickly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SteamBuildScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] list = new GameObject[3];
    public GameObject hand;
    public LayerMask layer;
    public Material handMat;
    public Material readyMat;
    public Material placeMatWall;
    public Material placeMatFoundation;
    public Material placeMatFloor;
    public MeshCollider box;
    int index = 0;
    public float foundationX;
    public float foundationY;
    public float foundationZ;
    public float wallX;
    public float wallY;
    public float wallZ;
    public float floorX;
    public float floorY;
    public float floorZ;
    public float wallXRotation, wallYRotation, wallZRotation;
    public bool activeGui;
    public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;
    public GameObject hammer;
    public Inventory inv;
    public GameObject cam;

    public AudioSource source;
    public bool hasInit = false;

    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();

    [Command]
    private void CmdInitialize()
    {
        RpcInit();
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdChangePos()
    {
        RpcChangePos();
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdTestButton()
    {
        RpcTestbutton();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void RpcInit()
    {
        hand = Instantiate(list[index]);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(hand, connectionToClient);

        hand.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = readyMat;
        hand.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;


        box = hand.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        box.enabled = false;
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void RpcChangePos()
    {
        hand.transform.position = hit.point + new Vector3(0, foundationY / 2, 0);
        hand.name = "Test";
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcTestbutton()
    {
        index = 1;
        Destroy(hand);
        hand = Instantiate(list[index]);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(hand, connectionToClient);
        box = hand.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        if (hand.tag == "Foundation")
        {
            hand.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = readyMat;
        }
        else if (hand.tag == "Wall")
        {
            hand.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = readyMat;
        }
        else if (hand.tag == "Floor")
        {
            hand.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = readyMat;
        }
        box.enabled = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer) { return; }

        if (hammer.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "ProcGame" && !hasInit)
            {
                {
                    CmdInitialize();
                    hasInit = true;
                }
            }

            if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, 20, layer))
            {
                if (hit.collider.transform != hand.transform)
                {   // if we look ground 
                    if (hit.collider.name == "Terrain Chunk")
                    {
                        if (hit.collider.transform != hand.transform && hand.tag == "Foundation")
                        {
                            CmdChangePos();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log("You cant place it without foundation");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
            {
                CmdTestButton();
            }
            
        }       
    }
}
```

I have gone back and forth between commands and rpc's for everything, I still get a bit confused over all of that
The cube does have a network identity/transform.
The script is on a player object which has a network Identity.
I have tried swapping client to server/server to client
I have tried using [command(requires authority = null)] instead of just [command]
I have switched on and off the tick box for client authority on the cube that spawns

The code will look a bit off probably, I have just been trying everything possible that I know and cannot seem to get this to sync correctly.

Thanks a bunch in advanced out there to anyone who can help :)

Comment: In general.. you only pass on the method calls to sever and back .. but not any parameters => whatever is called you always use the current local values for execution of the local rpc .. in particular the `RpcChangePos()` uses the **local** (=> for each client different) `hit.point` .. instead you should rather pass this one along in round trip `CmdChangePos(Vector3 hitPoint) { RpcChangePos(hitPoint);}`

Comment: The se goes for other things as well like e.g. `NetworkServer.Spawn(hand, connectionToClient);` .. you are spawning a couple of detached objects each for the individual local clients as owners .. that doesn't make sense

Comment: Oh I see, since I posted this I got it to work by making the entire if (physics.raycst..) a command rather than what I had. It was still flashing but I looked at the network transform and saw it was set as client to server, switched that at run time and it just snapped in place!

Comment: I face a new problem now.. and that is the gameobject being duplicated from the RPC,  if I have the hand = instantiate.. and networkserver.spawn(hand) as a command rather than the rpc within the command, no duplicates! But then I face another problem.. the client cannot take control of the cube because since it is now a command, hand will just = null, god this can be hard and confusing..

Comment: Networking is no magic .. whatever you want to reference on the other client sides needs to be passed along over the network... you should pass on your owner client id into the command, then on the server call the `SpawnWithAuthority` and pass in the owner ID .. no RPC should be done at all since the Network spawn already **is** synchronized itself